# RXJS buffer observable with max and min size

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

i am quite noob in rxjs.
i want a buffer which basically starts small in size (minSize) until it reaches a certain limit maxSize.

```
buffer(minSize, maxSize, startEvery)
```

so it should emit e.g (rxjs 6 syntax).

```
source(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).pipe(buffer(2, 4, 1))
.subscribe( res => console.log(res));

-> [1,2]
-> [1,2,3]
-> [1,2,3,4]
-> [2,3,4,5]
-> [3,4,5,6] 
and so on
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scan`:

```
of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).pipe(
    scan((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur].slice(-4), [])
).subscribe(arr => console.log(arr))
```

That will output:

```
[1]
[1,2]
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4]
[2,3,4,5]
[3,4,5,6]
```

If you want to get rid with the `[1]` use `scan(), skip(1)`

Comment: Nice. Earlier, I thought about posting an almost-identical snippet, but then I saw that the question also included a `startEvery` parameter - which makes it a little more complicated, I think. +1 though.

Comment: im not really interested in the startevery, can be constant for me at 1. so i accept the answer. thx a lot